# VS Code Hypersnips Extension: snippets defined in math context does not work with rmarkdown (.Rmd) files

Tags: r-markdown, vscode-extensions, code-snippets

I tried to use the VS Code Hypersnips extension (https://github.com/draivin/hsnips) for rmarkdown files. The extension works well with markdown files and latex files, but for some reason I cannot get it to work properly with rmarkdown.

For example, I define the following math contexts in the global setting first:

```
     function math(context) {
            return context.scopes.some(s => s.includes("math"));
        }

    // inline & block math

        function inline_math(context){
            return context.scopes.some(s => s.includes("math.inline"));
        }

        function block_math(context){
            return context.scopes.some(s => s.includes("math.block")) || context.scopes.some(s => s.includes("math.display"));
        }
```

However, snippets defined in these math context such as the following do not activate when the trigger is typed:

```
context math(context)
snippet `(;;;|cdot)` "cdots" iA
``rv='\\cdots'``
endsnippet

context math(context)
snippet `par` "partial" iA
``rv="\\partial "``
endsnippet
```

In contrast, snippets defined without the context definition activate properly, such as:

```
snippet `\\dm` "display math" bA
$$
$1
$$
$0
endsnippet
```

I cannot figure out why. I tried to store the snippets in a rmd.hsnips, Rmd.hsnips, rmarkdown.hsnips, and Rmarkdown.hsnips in the designated directory, but the above issue persists.

Thank you for your help.